# Case expressions in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can you use `case` expressions in Access? I'm trying to determine the max date form 2 columns but keep getting syntax errors in the following code:

```
CASE 
  WHEN dbo_tbl_property.LASTSERVICEDATE > Contour_dates.[Last CP12 Date]
    THEN dbo_tbl_property.LASTSERVICEDATE 
  ELSE Contour_dates.[Last CP12 Date] 
END AS MaxDate
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use the `IIF()` function instead.

```
IIF(condition, valueiftrue, valueiffalse)
```

- `condition` is the value that you want to test.
- `valueiftrue` is the value that is returned if condition evaluates to TRUE.
- `valueiffalse` is the value that is returned if condition evaluates to FALSE.

There is also the [`Switch`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379) function which is easier to use and understand when you have multiple conditions to test:

```
Switch( expr-1, value-1 [, expr-2, value-2 ] … [, expr-n, value-n ] )
```

> The Switch function argument list consists of pairs of expressions and
>   values. The expressions are evaluated from left to right, and the
>   value associated with the first expression to evaluate to True is
>   returned. If the parts aren't properly paired, a run-time error
>   occurs. For example, if expr-1 is True, Switch returns value-1. If
>   expr-1 is False, but expr-2 is True, Switch returns value-2, and so
>   on.
>
> Switch returns a Null value if:
>
> - None of the expressions is True.
> - The first True expression has a corresponding value that is Null.
>
> **NOTE: Switch evaluates all of the expressions**, even though it returns only one of them. For this reason, you should watch for
>   undesirable side effects. For example, if the evaluation of any
>   expression results in a division by zero error, an error occurs.

Comment: i thought you had to have a true flase answer to do that?

Comment: "dbo_tbl_property.LASTSERVICEDATE > Contour_dates.[Last CP12 Date]" is your true/false

Answer (score 9):

There is no case statement in Access. Instead you can use switch statement. It will look something like the one below:

`switch(dbo_tbl_property.LASTSERVICEDATE > Contour_dates.[Last CP12 Date],dbo_tbl_property.LASTSERVICEDATE,dbo_tbl_property.LASTSERVICEDATE <= Contour_dates.[Last CP12 Date],Contour_dates.[Last CP12 Date])`

For further reading look at:
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php

Or for case function implementation example in VBA:

http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2006/02/adding_case_to_.html

Regards,
J.

Comment: The `switch` function is a much better function to use if there are more multiple conditions being evaluated. It will be easier to read/understand/maintain compared to using nested `IIF` functions. Also, an alternate way to implement a default value instead of creating a logical expressions that basically evaluates to "all the previous expressions are false", is to just use `true` as the final expression to be evaluated. For example `switch(dbo_tbl_property.LASTSERVICEDATE > Contour_dates.[Last CP12 Date], dbo_tbl_property.LASTSERVICEDATE, true ,Contour_dates.[Last CP12 Date])`

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are dealing with numbers, `CASE` is just [syntactic sugar](https://www.quora.com/What-is-syntactic-sugar-in-programming-languages).  You can replace it with some boolean multiplication.

For example, `CASE WHEN A = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 3 END` is just a nicer way of writing

```
(-1) * ((A = 1) * 2 + (A <> 1) * 3)
```

(The `-1` is needed because Microsoft Jet [evaluates true boolean statements to -1](https://superuser.com/questions/694919/why-do-yes-no-values-in-microsoft-access-map-to-1-and-0/710356).)

So instead of:

```
CASE 
  WHEN dbo_tbl_property.LASTSERVICEDATE > Contour_dates.[Last CP12 Date]
    THEN dbo_tbl_property.LASTSERVICEDATE 
  ELSE Contour_dates.[Last CP12 Date] 
END AS MaxDate
```

Use:

```
-1 * (
(dbo_tbl_property.LASTSERVICEDATE > Contour_dates.[Last CP12 Date]) * dbo_tbl_property.LASTSERVICEDATE +
(dbo_tbl_property.LASTSERVICEDATE <= Contour_dates.[Last CP12 Date]) * Contour_dates.[Last CP12 Date]
) AS MaxDate
```

By the way, sadly, if your CASE statement involves strings, this method does not work.