# Access/jet equivalent of Oracle's decode

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, jet

Is there an equivalent for Oracle's decode() in Access (or Jet, for that matter).

The problem I am facing is: I should sort (order) a resultset based basically upon 
a status and a date (with all records having status = 2) at the end.

In Oracle I'd go something like

```
select
  ...
from
  ...
where
  ..
order by
  decode(status, 2, 0, 1),
  date_column
```

Comment: You can write a custom function in VBA and then call it from your SQL. This may be preferable if you have complex choices, else solutions below Switch or Iif below are best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest analogy is the `SWITCH()` function e.g.

Oracle:

```
SELECT supplier_name,
       decode(supplier_id,  10000, 'IBM',
                            10001, 'Microsoft',
                            10002, 'Hewlett Packard',
                                   'Gateway') result
  FROM suppliers;
```

Access Database Engine

```
SELECT supplier_name,
       SWITCH(supplier_id = 10000, 'IBM',
              supplier_id = 10001, 'Microsoft',
              supplier_id = 10002, 'Hewlett Packard',
              TRUE, 'Gateway') AS result
  FROM suppliers;
```

Note that with the `SWITCH()` function you have to supply the full predicate each time, so you are not restricted to using just supplier_id. For the default value, use a predicate that is obvious to the human reader that it is TRUE e.g. `1 = 1` or indeed simply `TRUE` :)

Something that may not be obvious is that the logic in the `SWITCH()` function doesn't short circuit, meaning that every expression in the function must be able to be evaluated without error. If you require logic to short circuit then you will need to use nested `IIF()` functions.

Comment: In Access-2010, the IIF function in SQL is *not* short-circuit.  Based on both the documentation and empirical testing.

Comment: @user36800 ...but if you have proof that it cannot short circuit then please post somewhere somehow and I pledge to test it :)

Comment: The `IIf` function in the Access db engine's implementation does indeed short circuit;  VBA `IIf` does not.  If @user36800 wants to confirm that point empirically, it's easy. In an Access query, `SELECT IIf(True,2,1/0)` returns 2.  In VBA, the same `IIf` expression triggers run-time error 11: *"Division by zero"*.

Comment: I'm running into this problem now, 2 years after my erroneous comment.  Yes, empirical testing shows that SQL IIF is short-circuiting (and I'm using SQL 92).  It's precisely the behaviour I need right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with IIF. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772461/case-statement-in-access) stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might compare to switch or choose.

```
Switch(expr-1, value-1[, expr-2, value-2 … [, expr-n,value-n]])
```

-- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA012289181033.aspx

```
Choose(index, choice-1[, choice-2, ... [, choice-n]])
```

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262690%28VS.60%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SWITCH` function:

```
LABEL: Switch(
   [TABLE_NAME]![COL_NAME]='VAL1';'NEW_VAL1';
   [TABLE_NAME]![COL_NAME]='VAL2';'NEW_VAL2';
)
```

Note semicolons and not commas.

The example above works in queries in MS Access 2010.