# converting SQL to ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

here's a regular SQL statement:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [Column2] = 'Cylinder' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Cylinder count',
SUM(CASE WHEN [Column2] = 'Snap' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Snap count',
SUM(CASE WHEN [Column2] = 'Tip' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Tip count',
SUM(CASE WHEN [Column2] = 'Other' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Other count'
FROM [TableName]
WHERE [Column1] = '1.9 QNS-Quantity Not Sufficient'
```

can you please convert it to ms-access??

based on this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153829/question-on-complex-select-statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Access doesn't support CASE, but you can use IIF instead:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IIF([Column2] = 'Cylinder', 1, 0)) as 'Cylinder count',
    SUM(IIF([Column2] = 'Snap', 1, 0)) as 'Snap count',
    SUM(IIF([Column2] = 'Tip', 1, 0)) as 'Tip count',
    SUM(IIF([Column2] = 'Other', 1, 0)) as 'Other count'
FROM [TableName]
WHERE [Column1] = '1.9 QNS-Quantity Not Sufficient'
```

**References**

- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx
- [Case expressions in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772461/case-statement-in-access)

Comment: I don't think you need the quotes around the field aliases.