# Comparing dates within SUM- CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am working with a table similar to the following one:

```
PBName          InputDate     Amount

Michael Brown   07-jan-13     1391000,000 €
Mary Aspas      07-jan-13     -400000,000 €
Thomas Dand     15-feb-13     3000000,000 €
Mary Aspas      31-jul-13     3000000,000 €
```

Then, I am just trying to get the total amount by PBName when InputDate is previous to a given one:

```
Dim dd As Date

dd = 15-feb-13
```

This is the code I am using:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Rea.PBName, SUM(CASE WHEN Rea.InputDate < dd THEN Rea.AMOUNT / 1000000 ELSE 0 END) As NNARea "
```

When I try to run the query I get the message "invalid column name".

Could you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have a `FROM schema.Table` anywhere in your query

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @jle The `vba` tag makes me think `Access`

Comment: If it is access, there is no CASE statement--he will have to use IIF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772461/case-statement-in-access

Comment: also you will need "group by" if you want sums.

Comment: what I usually to:  make a new access-query, that does what I need in my vba-code. Then look at the SQL-code of the query and paste&copy into the vba-code, and insert any references needed like to your "dd"

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you...

```
strSQL = "SELECT PBName, SUM(Amount)/1000000 AS NNARea " & _
         "FROM Rea " & _
         "WHERE InputDate < #" & dd & "# " & _
         "GROUP BY PBName;"
```