# How do I get Average IF statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, average

I have table in MS Access with columns Year, Period (values just `1` and `2`), Costs_Per_Capita and CALCULATED_Period_Avg_Costs, PK is ID.

I need to calculate `CALCULATED_Period_Avg_Costs`. It should return average of `Costs_Per_Capita` for given period from `Period` column. In Excel I do this with SUMIF/COUNTIF which returns Average IF.

Do you have some advice how to write a code in SQL to do that?

Results should look like:

```
Costs_Per_Capita    Period              CALCULATED_Period_Avg_Costs
15,505              1                   15976.27582
16,368              1                   15976.27582
16,037              1                   15976.27582
15,995              1                   15976.27582
15,000              2                   16000
17,000              2                   16000
```

I used statement:

```
SELECT 
Costs_Per_Capita, Period
IFF (Period = 1, 
(Select AVG(Costs_Per_Capita) From Costs Where Period = 1), 
(Select AVG(Costs_Per_Capita) From Costs Where Period = 2) 
AS result
FROM Costs;
```

Still gets "syntax error (missing operator) in a query expression ..."

Comment: What is the question? What did you try so far? Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi, i have function averege if in Excel and i would like to do the same in sql/ms access query.

Comment: I suggest you to update your question, add more details and share what you tried, and what problems appeared since you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: i see your point, thanks. I updated question. This was my first post..sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're asking for and I believe this is what you're looking for -

```
Select
    Costs_Per_Capita,
    Related_Period_ID,
    (Select 
        Case when Related_Period_ID = 1 then 
        (Select
            AVG(Costs_Per_Capita)
            From Costs_Per_Capita_Table
            Where Related_Period_ID = 1)
        else 
       (Select
            AVG(Costs_Per_Capita)
            From Costs_Per_Capita_Table
            Where Related_Period_ID = 2)
        END 
    )
    From
    Costs_Per_Capita_Table
```

Changing     CASE to     IFF

```
Select 
        IFF (Related_Period_ID = 1, 
        (Select
            AVG(Costs_Per_Capita)
            From Costs_Per_Capita_Table
            Where Related_Period_ID = 1),
       (Select
            AVG(Costs_Per_Capita)
            From Costs_Per_Capita_Table
            Where Related_Period_ID = 2)
```

Comment: thanks! statement seems like what i need. I just modified names of table and columns like that:                     Select 
       Costs_Per_Capita, Period,  
       (Select 
             Case when Period = 1 then 
             (Select 
              AVG(Costs_Per_Capita) From Costs 
              Where Period = 1)
        else 
        (Select 
              AVG(Costs_Per_Capita)
              From Costs 
              Where Period = 2) 
              END)
    From
    Costs                                                                 I got a error message "syntax error in query expression

Comment: AH! Well the error is definitely in the fact that I was using SQL language and not Access language - you might need to rewrite it according to the syntax of the Access language (rather than using SQL that I used here) - but the idea, I would assume, is basically the same - 
    If Period is 1 then use some avg function for Capita if period is 2 then use avg function for Capita

Comment: Well looking at this the syntax looks pretty much the same: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-sql-basic-concepts-vocabulary-and-syntax-HA010256402.aspx

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the ; at the end of the query

Comment: And doing some MORE research - CASE statement in SQL - is IFF statement in Access so I believe that might be the real problem in all this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772461/case-statement-in-access

Comment: i used statement as you recommended but still gets error, see my statement above. I appreciate your help so much!

Answer (score 0):

I did this with:
SELECT Costs.Costs_Per_Capita, Costs.Period,

IIF(Costs.Period = 1,

(Select AVG(Costs_Per_Capita) From Costs Where Period = 1),

(Select AVG(Costs_Per_Capita) From Costs Where Period = 2))

AS result

FROM Costs;

other way, better if more periods apper is using subquery:

SELECT Costs.Period, Costs.Costs_Per_Capita, tmpQry.CALCULATED_Period_Avg_Costs

FROM Costs INNER JOIN (SELECT Costs.Period, Avg(Costs.Costs_Per_Capita)

AS CALCULATED_Period_Avg_Costs FROM Costs

GROUP BY Costs.Period)  AS tmpQry ON Costs.Period = tmpQry.Period;

maybe someone will use it later on...

Answer (score -1):

```
Select CostsPerCapital, Period, avg(CostPerCapita) over (partition by Period)
From Table
Where....
Order by ...
```