# Converting sql case expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, case

I'm trying to take the following sql case statement and convert it to Access 2010 as a calculation for a column. I've looked at the IIF statements but have received errors trying to sort it out. Thank you for any help.

```
case 
   when left(Tiers,4) = 'Tier' and isnumeric(right((left(Tiers,7)),2)) = 1 then right((left(Tiers,7)),2)
   when left(Tiers,4) = 'Tier' and isnumeric(right((left(Tiers,7)),2)) = 0 then right((left(Tiers,6)),1)
   else Tiers
end
```

;

Comment: yeah... you are going to need to show us what you tried and what errors you got otherwise this isn't a question it is a request for a consultant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case expressions in Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772461/case-expressions-in-access)

Answer (score 0):

you can only use Case statements in access in VBA Code. 
and iif should work as well in access 
like this 
`iif(left(Tiers,4) ='Tire',iif(isnumeric(right((left(Tiers,7)),2)) = 1,right((left(Tiers,7)),2),right((left(Tiers,6)),1)), Tires)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIF() as you mentioned and it will likely be a pain.  There is also SWITCH function available which will likely make it easier for you to convert your case statement instead of nested IIF()s

Switch( expr-1, value-1 [, expr-2, value-2 ] … [, expr-n, value-n ] )

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379

This is a duplicate question of:
[Case expressions in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772461/case-expressions-in-access).