# Use VBA in ACCESS to run SQl with CASE statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am using VBA to write 0/1 in a column of my table in Access.
If the difference between the dates contained in the two columns [IsYTD?] and [SO Tarihi]) is <365 I would like to write 1 in [IsYTD?] while a 0 in the other case. This is my code for the moment but it doesn't seem to work. Can you help me?

```
   SQL3 = "UPDATE [1 - CURRENT RAW DATA SOURCE] SET [IsYTD?] = CASE " & _
    "WHEN ([IsYTD?]-[SO Tarihi])<365 THEN 1 " & _
    "ELSE 0 " & _
    "END"
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL3
```

Comment: Access doesn't support CASE expressions, you need to use [`IIF`](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php) pr [`SWITCH`](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php) instead. Possible duplicate of [Case expressions in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/772461/1048425).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case expressions in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772461/case-expressions-in-access)

Answer (score 1):

`CASE WHEN` is not valid syntax in MS Access SQL. Use either [switch](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php) or [iif()](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php)

Since you only have 2 cases, `iif` is simpler to code

```
 SQL3 = "UPDATE [1 - CURRENT RAW DATA SOURCE] SET [IsYTD?] = iif(([IsYTD?]-[SO Tarihi])<365, 1,0)"
```