# Can mathematical operators be used in a query in a select statement?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, case

I'm trying to `INNER JOIN` two tables: `tbl_profile` and `tbl_employment`

`tbl_profile` has:

```
    id_no (pk)
    lastName (String)
    firstName (String)
```

`tbl_employment` has:

```
    company_no (pk)
    id_no (fk)
    datehired (date)
    company (string)
    end_employment (date)
```

Each person in the `profile` table can have many employments or none at all in life. But I need to find the latest `date_hired` of that person.

These are the conditions I want to set:

- if the date_hired of the person is not empty and the end_employment is empty, it means that the person is CURRENTLY EMPLOYED
- if the date_hired of the person is not empty and the end_employment is also not empty, it means that the person is CURRENTLY UNEMPLOYED
- if the date_hired of the person is empty, then it means that the
  person is UNEMPLOYED.

After determining the conditions above, my query will add another column named `STATUS` which will only state `EMPLOYED` or `UNEMPLOYED` based on the conditions above.

However, when I convert this logic into a query, it states

> Syntax Error: Operator is missing.

I read a book about using `when`-`then` statement like `if`-`else` does in `SELECT` of a query is possible. But with my query, it doesn't work. What is wrong with this?

```
SELECT p.id_no, p.lastName ,
(CASE
    WHEN c.date_hired != "" AND c.end_employment = "" THEN 'employed'
    WHEN c.date_hired != "" AND c.end_employment != "" THEN 'unemployed'
    WHEN c.date_hired = "" THEN 'unemployed'
END)
AS employment_status
FROM tbl_profile AS p INNER JOIN tbl_employment AS c ON p.id_no= c.id_no;
```

It says that the error is within this part:

```
(CASE
       WHEN c.date_hired != "" AND c.end_employment = "" THEN 'employed'
       WHEN c.date_hired != "" AND c.end_employment != "" THEN 'unemployed'
       WHEN c.date_hired = "" THEN 'unemployed'    END)
```

P.S: I did the query in Microsoft Access

Comment: I'd say the first things that's wrong is that you try to compare NULL date values to empty string. Handle them as date values and check for NULL.

Comment: tried it with is null and is not null. STILL NOT WORKING @Filburt

Comment: Why does your query use `tbl_company` while your question starts with `tbl_employment`?

Comment: @trincot sorry typo. i will correct it here. but on my ms access, its typed right and its still NOT WORKING.

Comment: No need to shout. What is `alumni_no, p.lname`? Those fields are not in your description. Is the first one the key? Please do an effort to make your question consistent.

Comment: I had several jobs - some of them overlapping, some of them interleaving - some starting ending after / in / between when I had others. Thats a case in your data? _Job1_ starts in Januar, Ends in Mai, _Job2_ starts in Februar, ends in _October_, Job3 starts in April, Ends in April, _Job4 starts in Februar and ends 2 years later. Employed all the time, sometims working more then 1 job.

Comment: @PatrickArtner What do you mean sir? I dont understand. I dont see backlashes in my query or in the error

Comment: See [coalesce alternative in Access SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/247858/205233) to handle NULL `date_hired`and `end_employment` values. Use something like `Nz(date_hired, your_default_date_here)`.

Comment: @trincot oh sorry. im not shouting. sorry. and ive changed that. its still not working. im reading sql case-when-then now and i really dont find the error and what the syntax error and missing operator is.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from `!=` which is not a valid comparison operator in MS Access. There is [`<>`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Table-of-operators-e1bc04d5-8b76-429f-a252-e9223117d6bd), but although that would be valid it would not be what you need:

You are comparing dates with empty strings, which is a bit odd. I suppose your dates are stored in a column that has the appropriate date data type. You should instead check whether the value is `null` or not.

Also, your query will not find persons who do not have any record in `tbl_employment`. You need an outer join for that.

Finally, your query would not prevent you from getting multiple results for the same person: you need to group the results. I would suggest `MIN` so that cases where you get both `employed` and `unemployed`, `employed` will be the overall conclusion.

Untested (I don't have MS Access):

```
SELECT     p.id_no,
           p.lastName, 
           MIN(IIF(c.date_hired IS NOT NULL AND c.end_employment IS NULL,
                   'employed',
                   'unemployed'
           )) AS employment_status
FROM       tbl_profile AS p 
LEFT JOIN  tbl_employment AS c 
        ON p.id_no = c.id_no
GROUP BY   p.id_no,
           p.lastName;
```

Note also the change of the `CASE WHEN` expression to `IIF`: [MS Access does not support the former](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772461/case-expressions-in-access).

Also, there is only one condition where the result is "employed": all other conditions signify unemployment, so they don't need to be verified separately.

Comment: How does `MIN` on the `case` work out? the earlier mentioned, the smaller or by `'em..' < 'un..'` due to lexicographical ordering? Probably the latter one?

Comment: Indeed, lexicographical ordering.

Comment: does not work. it still says syntax error (missing operator). is case-when-then-end even work on ms access? because the error it says is from MIN to END in your query

Comment: You could research that of course, but I have changed it to the non-standard `IIF` now, which I suppose MS Access supports.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
WHEN Coalesce(c.date_hired,"") != "" AND Coalesce(c.end_employment,"") = "" THEN 'employed' else 'unemployed'
```