# Query expression that shows either zero or one

Tags: sql, ms-access, formula

I am getting an error in my querys expression saying syntax error coma in query expression. what is wrong with it?

[FIXED] thanks Gustav

IIf(DCount("DateCompleted","tblEmployeeRequirements","EmpFuncID=" & [EmpFuncID])=DCount("*","tblEmployeeRequirements","EmpFuncID=" & [EmpFuncID] & ""),1,0)

Comment: Does that error go away if you change `If(` to `IIf(`?

Comment: No IIF says the expression you entered has a function containing the wrong number of arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should read:

```
IIf(DCount("*","tblEmployeeRequirements","EmpFuncID=" & [EmpFuncID] & "")=DCount("*","tblFunctionRequirements","FuncID =" & [FuncID] & ""),1,0)
```

Or:

```
Abs(DCount("*","tblEmployeeRequirements","EmpFuncID=" & [EmpFuncID] & "")=DCount("*","tblFunctionRequirements","FuncID =" & [FuncID] & ""))
```

Comment: Both give a answer of 1 all the time even its supposed to be zero.

Comment: ok, I split them and checked to see why and the two halfs are giving the same results thats the reason

Comment: IIf(DCount("DateCompleted","tblEmployeeRequirements","EmpFuncID=" & [EmpFuncID])=DCount("*","tblEmployeeRequirements","EmpFuncID=" & [EmpFuncID] & ""),1,0)

Comment: Those two parts will always return identical results as well.

Answer (score -1):

you should use IFF

checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772461/case-expressions-in-access):

Comment: didnt notice , he can use this then
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772461/case-expressions-in-access